# Trouble parsing parameters

Tags: go

I'm trying to use a simple method that will take the request and parse the parameters but it returns the wrong number of parameters.

In my main I make a request and then call:

`fmt.Println(parseParams(r, "http://localhost:8080", 2))`

which leads to following values being set in the method when logged:

**url:** `/api/users`

**params:** `[ api users]`

**len(params):** `3`

So it seems as if it think there's one extra param that I don't specify and looking at it more closely I can see theres a space before api in the params but I don't know where that comes from

```
func parseParams(req *http.Request, prefix string, num int) ([]string, error) {
    url := strings.TrimPrefix(req.URL.Path, prefix)
    params := strings.Split(url, "/")

    if len(params) != num || len(params[0]) == 0 || len(params[1]) == 0 {
        return nil, fmt.Errorf("Bad format. Expecting exactly %d params", num)
    }

    return params, nil
}
```

Comment: Of course there is: You did not strip the leading / from the URL Path.

Comment: To the person that voted to close because of off-topic could you please care to explain?.
@Volker I thought that the split method would do that but now I see exactly what it does. I just picked up Go yesterday coming from a javascript background so there's much to learn!

Comment: @Volker There's no need to come off as condescending. I have been reading the documentation but I as an individual do not learn well by documentation even by trying examples. I learn best by answers by people who can explain the concept how it would be explained face to face. You shouldn't assume things just as I didn't assume that's how split worked it's what I thought it did and it took someone explaining it in different terms than the documentation to understand it better.

Comment: Please excuse if I made a condescending statement, I didn't intend to. But please note that  rating on questions does not rate your need for an answer or how helpful an answer would be to you but how helpful and important the question is for others. As this is a very specific problem with a trivial underlying cause I do not think lots of other people will benefit from answers to this question.

Comment: @Volker I understand and I will close the question but the answer provided here taught me more than in 5 minutes than the documentation did in 1 hour. Thank you for your inputs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are seeing is not a space (that's just the separator), but an empty string, so the array looks like this `["", "api", "users"]`. If you take away the commas and quotes, it will look like your output.
So, your params are ""/"api"/"users". Usually, you can skip this 0-th index when processing the params.

Comment: Oh that makes much more sense now looking at it, I didnt even think of the quotes being stripped. Another question arises though, if I pass in `localhost:8080/` as the parameter for the prefix string, it still gives 3 as the length. Isn't it supposed to strip off the base so that it's `api/users` instead of `/api/users` now and then split would correctly remove the one slash and return 2?

Comment: @Mr.Smithyyy `localhost:8080/` is a host therefore it's doubtful that `r.URL.Path` contains that.

Comment: @Mr.Smithyyy ``localhost:8080`` is a host (with :port), and the ``/`` at the end is already part of the path, which thus is ``/api/users``.